# Defining an odd function with one formula

Tags: functions

The function $g(x)$ is odd. It is known that it is defined with the formula $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ for $x \ge 0$. The problem is to define the whole function with one formula.
After having looked at the function graphic, I have found that the formula is $\frac{|x|}{x} \sqrt{|x|}$. Is there any way to explain that result by using algebra, not graphics?

Comment: You could use $\operatorname{sgn}(x)\sqrt{|x|}$, I suppose.

Comment: I don't think that $\frac{|x|}{x}\sqrt{|x|}$ is a good answer, because it's undefined for $x = 0$. @kimchilover's expression much better.

Comment: Several of the answers and comments give you formulas. But I think the wish and search for  a single formula is not helpful or useful. It doesn't add to your (correct) intuition about what is going on, nor is it common in more advanced mathematics. The description in @paul 's answer is what you would see.

Answer (score 1):

Since $g$ is odd, you know that for any $x$ you have $g(-x) = -g(x)$. Essentially this means that if you know what the function looks like for positive $x$, you are guaranteed to know what it looks like for negative $x$ as well (it has the same value just with the opposite sign).

Answer (score 0):

Plug in a non-negative number $x\ge 0$:

$$\frac{|x|}x\sqrt{|x|}=\frac xx\sqrt x=\sqrt x.$$

Plug in a negative number $x<0$:

$$\frac{|x|}x\sqrt{|x|}=\frac{-x}x\sqrt {-x}=-\sqrt{-x}.$$

This should show you that you defined an odd function and that it matches $\sqrt x$ in the positive numbers.

Comment: do not plug in $0$!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Right. It works with the convention $0/0=1$.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

$$g(x)=x^{1/3}(x^2)^{1/12}$$

(where $x^{1/3}$ is the *real* cube root of $x$, hence negative if $x$ is negative).